# elasticsearch has a large delay dealing with java's log

Tags: elasticsearch

background arch:
filebeat -> kafka -> logstash -> elasticsearch

There is a delay of 1-3 hours for viewing logs in es.

kafka configuration:
topic: logcenter-product-resource-pool-log
partation: 6

logstash configuration:

```
pipeline.workers: 24
pipeline.batch.size: 3000
pipeline.batch.delay: 30
```

elastichsearch indice configuration:

```
"translog": {
  "flush_threshold_size": "1024mb",
  "sync_interval": "120s",
  "durability": "async"
}
"document size": 800G
"shards": 24
```

i try to increase the number of logstash worker from 16 to 24 but there was no improvement.

The ioutil of the physical machine has been maintained at 30%

Comment: `Kafka and Logstash`:
Monitor Kafka consumer lag and adjust Logstash batch settings cautiously.
`Elasticsearch`:

Consider tweaking shard count and monitor cluster health.
`General Optimization`:
Ensure disk I/O, network latency, and indexing patterns are not bottlenecks. Implement robust monitoring.